# Need help to input If and Vlookup formula into cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I created a button which adds a new job entry into my job database. Based on the value in `Cells (emptyRow,40)`, Vlookup with search **"Job Category"** Worksheet and output the results in `Cells (emptyRow,43)`. Hence, each time I am adding a new job entry, I would like `Cells(emptyRow,43)` to input the formula and tell me what job this falls under, as shown below

```
Dim emptyRow As Long
emptyRow = Range("Z100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(emptyRow, 43).Formula = "=IF(Cells(emptyRow,40)=0, "", VLOOKUP(Cells(emptyRow,40),'Job Category'!$G$10:$I$12, 3, TRUE))"
```

However, I get this message: `"Run-time error '1004' : Application-defined or object-defined error."`

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mashing together worksheet function syntax and VBA syntax. While you can use a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) to return the result from a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65), it seems that you want to write the formula into the cell. This may be better as an xlR1C1 style formula due to the emptyRow variable.

```
'as an xlA1 style
 Cells(emptyRow, 43).Formula = _
    "=IF(AN" & emptyRow & "=0, """", VLOOKUP(AN" & emptyRow & ",'Job Category'!$G$10:$I$12, 3, TRUE))"
'as an xlR1C1 style
 Cells(emptyRow, 43).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC40=0, """", VLOOKUP(RC40, 'Job Category'!R10C7:R12C9, 3, TRUE))"
```

Remember that when including quotes within a quoted string, you need to double up the quotes.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you and everyone else for helping!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim emptyRow As Long, addr as string
emptyRow = Range("Z100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
addr = Cells(emptyRow,40).Address()

Cells(emptyRow, 43).Formula = "=IF(" & addr & "=0, """", VLOOKUP(" & _
                              addr & ",'Job Category'!$G$10:$I$12, 3, TRUE))"
```

Comment: Missed that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use iferror as well,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    emptyRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(emptyRow, 43).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AN" & emptyRow & ",'Job Category'!$G$10:$I$12,3,1),"""")"

End Sub
```